# Storing state in a Node/Express application

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I'm writing a Node/Express app (my first) and need help persisting what feels like a global variable across page loads; but using a global variable feels wrong.

For the purposes of the question, the site is essentially 3 different table views on the same data. The data in the tables is taken from 3 separate MongoDB tables, merged together with a function, and displayed (using Pug, iterating over the object I just created).

The 3 different views are just different Pug templates iterating over the same object.

I have middleware which generates this object from MongoDB and stores it on `res.locals`, but I don't want to re-generate it by default every time the user selects a different view. The data hasn't changed, and this feels wasteful.

I want to be able to set some sort of variable, `dataNeedsToBeUpdated`, and if `true` then the function inside my middleware will actually do the work and regenerate the table; if `false`, it'll just skip the operation.

If the user performs one of my update operations, I'll set `dataNeedsToBeUpdated = true`, redirect, middleware will fire, and the data will refresh before the next page load.

How do I do this properly?

Comment: what about http session data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`app.locals` works just about like `res.locals`, just it's available to the whole app. You can access it in middleware from `req.app.locals`. The flow as you've described it sounds good; just use `app.locals` for storing the data and the `dataNeedsToBeUpdated`.

Comment: Great, thanks. I'll give that a try some time this week and report back here. Appreciate the response.